# Use of % in scanf and printf

Tags: c, scanf

What is the exact use of `%` in `scanf` and `printf`? And would `scanf` and `printf` work without the `%` sign? All I could find is that `%` is the conversion specifier but I want to know how it works actually?

Comment: http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html

Comment: What did you try? Where did you search? What of the extensive, freely available documentation did you read?

Comment: `printf` can work without `%` sign. If you don't want formatted output. Eg. printf("Hello Sunny");

Comment: You mean you want a rewrite that does not match anyone else's homework submissions?

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` is simply the symbol used to identify the beginning of a conversion specifier in the format string; why `%` as opposed to any other symbol is an open question, and probably doesn't have that interesting an answer.  The `printf` and `scanf` functions search the format string for conversion specifiers to tell them the number and types of additional arguments to expect, and how to format the output (for `printf`) or interpret the input (for `scanf`).

To print a literal `%`, you need to use `%%`.

`printf` can work without using a conversion specifier, but you'll be limited to writing literal strings.  `scanf` is pretty useless without it.

Answer (score 1):

The `'%'` character is used in the **format string** of the `scanf()` and `print()`-like functions from the standard header `<stdio.h>`, to indicate **place holders** for variable data of several kinds. For example, the **format specifier** `"%d"` is a place holder for a value having type `int`.

Thus, the variadic function `printf()` expects additional parameters passed as arguments to the function, the first of them having type `int`.

The value of this `int` argument is converted to string, and it will be replace to the place holder `"%d"`.

In the case of `scanf()`, the situation is similar, but now `scanf()` is an **input function** that expects that the user enters in command-line a value fitting on the type indicated by the format specifier. Thus, a format specifier `"%d"` will expect that the user enters a value of type `int`.

Since all the arguments in **C** are passed by value, the input data requires you use the address of the variable, to mimic a *by-reference* mode of passing arguments.

There are a lot of options and details related to these format specifiers.
Yo need to take a look at the bibliography.
For example, start in Wikipedia:

[printf() format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)
[scanf()  format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string)

Answer (score 1):

The `%` in a `scanf()` or `printf()` is a keyword whose purpose is identify the type of data that will be stored in the named variable. So, in the following example, the compiler would build instructions to accept input data of type integer and store it in the memory location at the address assigned to `num1`:

```
int num1;
scanf("%d",&num1);
```